# What's the difference between -sS and -sT on nmap?

Tags: networking, nmap

What's the difference between -sS and -sT on nmap?
Both commands give the same output (besides filtered ports/closed ports).

Answer (score 4):

#### What's the difference between -sS and -sT on nmap?

> **SCAN TYPES**
>
> -sS TCP SYN scan:
>
> This technique is often referred to as "half-open"
>                 scanning, because you don’t open a full TCP connection. You send
>                 a SYN packet, as if you are going to open a real connection  and
>                 you wait for a response. A SYN|ACK indicates the port is listen-
>                 ing. A RST is indicative of a non-listener.   If  a  SYN|ACK  is
>                 received,  a RST is immediately sent to tear down the connection
>                 (actually our OS kernel does this for us). The primary advantage
>                 to  this  scanning  technique  is  that fewer sites will log it.
>                 Unfortunately you need root privileges to build these custom SYN
>                 packets.  This is the default scan type for privileged users.
>
> -sT    TCP connect() scan:
>
> This is the most basic form of TCP scanning.
>                 The connect() system call provided by your operating  system  is
>                 used  to  open  a  connection  to  every interesting port on the
>                 machine. If the port is listening, connect() will succeed,  oth
>                 erwise  the  port  isn’t reachable. One strong advantage to this
>                 technique is that you don’t need  any  special  privileges.  Any
>                 user on most UNIX boxes is free to use this call.
>
> This  sort of scan is easily detectable as target host logs will
>                 show a bunch of connection and error messages for  the  services
>                 which  accept() the connection just to have it immediately shut-
>                 down.  This is the default scan type for unprivileged users.

Source [nmap](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/nmap1.html)

Answer (score 0):

With -sS the TCP the packet flow is SYN - SYN/ACK - RST. The service that is listening on the port won't notice since the handshake never completes. On the other hand, -sT performs a proper handshake (SYN - SYN/ACK - ACK) which establishes a connection, so the service notices.

Thus, -sS is stealthier than -sT.